# Strange Nginx redirection with other slash

Tags: nginx, redirect, nginx-config

Hey guys I noticed a strange redirection with check redirecter I don't know where 302 redirection come from "v2.domain.com//: (I m using wordpress) if you have any suggestion for good config !

```
Result
https:// example.com
302 Moved Temporarily
https:// v2.example.com//
301 Moved Permanently
https:// v2.example.com/
200 OK
```

This is my nginx default enabled sites config for my wordpress site:

```
# Default server configuration
    #
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
    
        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;
    
        root /var/www/html/domain.com/public_html;
    
        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    
        server_name domain.com;
    
        location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
            if ($http_host !~ "^v2.example.com"){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ https:// v2.example.com/$1 redirect;
      }
        }
    
        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
            #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
    
        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #   deny all;
        #}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rewrite...redirect` performs an external redirection using a 302 status. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

In the following expression:

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ https://v2.example.com/$1 redirect;
```

The capture `$1` includes the first character of the URI, which in Nginx is always a `/`.

Either of the following will avoid the `//`:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://v2.example.com/$1 redirect;
rewrite ^(.*)$ https://v2.example.com$1 redirect;
```

Comment: I've got a 302 redirection not 301 how I can do that ?

Comment: Replace `redirect` with `permanent` and Nginx uses 301 instead of 302.